# iphone app display strange on iPad when landscape

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8, landscape

i developed an iPhone app.look at the pictures, the view controller only set to support portrait.i install it on iPad air,when orientation is portrait ,everything seems to be ok.but when the orientation changes to landscape,the view on iPad was cut by 2 parts and a wide black line,it's iOS8 system problem i think, because i never add code for this kind of situation.also happens on iPad mini,but the simulator was ok.Any body knows why ? if it could be fixed,any solution ? thank u guys so much for any suggestion!

[image: real device has problem]
[image: simulator is ok]

Comment: please click the link to check the photos

Comment: anybody know ? ... i am waiting...

Comment: Having the same problem here.. Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: noooooo, the apple guys said it is interesting...... so it's a system bug.leave it.